# How do I compare a time difference with a number of seconds in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a condition for expiration in Postgres. I've got a vartiable `last_sync::timestamp` and a limit `86400 * 30` seconds. I tried this way:

```
NOW() - last_sync > 86400 * 30
```

But it gives an error: no operator for interval > integer.

I would like to make it work even if `last_sunc` is `-infinity`.

How can I do this comparison correctly?

Comment: You have a interval between timestamp on the left, you probably need to convert this in seconds

Comment: So how can I do it?

Comment: Have you read [How do I convert an interval into a number of hours with postgres?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952493/how-do-i-convert-an-interval-into-a-number-of-hours-with-postgres) or [How to convert an interval like “1 day 01:30:00” into “25:30:00”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/341384/4391450)

Comment: I have. It looks complicated for my problem. Maybe there's a better way for expiration.

Comment: You need to convert this interval into a number of seconds, the second links clearly answer this. An other solution would be to substract `86400*30` to NOW() and compare it to `last_sync`. This will give you two timestamp to compare, this is easier (or add the value to last_sync ;) )

Comment: Thanks @AxelH. I would like to have a look at other suggestions too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use intervals ==> [Date/Time Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

```
create table asd(
   name varchar(20),
   last_sync timestamp
)
;

insert into asd values( 'one', now() - interval '500' hour );
insert into asd values( 'two', now() - interval '1500' hour );


SELECT * 
from asd
where NOW() - last_sync > ( 86400 * 30 ) * INTERVAL '1' second

name |last_sync           |
-----|--------------------|
two  |2016-10-26 00:52:16 |
```

---

> How to make it work if last_sync is -infinity? – Fomalhaut 5 mins ago

```
insert into asd values( 'one', now() - interval '500' hour );
insert into asd values( 'two', now() - interval '1500' hour );

insert into asd values( 'minus infinity', timestamp '-infinity' );
insert into asd values( 'plus infinity', timestamp 'infinity' );


SELECT * 
from asd
where last_sync > NOW() - ( 86400 * 30 ) * INTERVAL '1' second

name          |last_sync                |
--------------|-------------------------|
one           |2016-12-06 15:52:12      |
plus infinity |292278994-08-17 00:00:00 |
```

Comment: I've added an example how to check for infinity

Comment: Thanks! I had used this expression `last_sync < NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days'` and it worked.

Comment: And looking at your nickname I want to say: Привет из Москвы!

Answer (score 2):

You can convert `86400 * 30` to an `interval` of seconds:

```
interval '2592000 second'
```

Then you can compare:

```
select (now() - '2016-12-02') > interval '2592000 second';
```

This select returns:

```
False
```

You can convert `integer` to `interval`:

```
(86400 * 30) * interval '1 second'
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can it work with `last_sync = -infinity`?

Answer (score -1):

If you read this as a Mathematician

```
NOW() - last_sync > 86400 * 30
```

would be equals to

```
NOW() > 86400 * 30 + last_sync
```

With the first line, you have `interval > integer` with the second line, you have `timestamp > timestamp`. No problem of type with the last one.

I don't know PostgreSQL enought to write the solution but you have a good start with that solution. Using the correct function to add a value to a timestamp.

Comment: Same problem: `no operator for integer + timestamp`

Comment: If you tried using the code I have written, this seems logic since this was just a pseudocode... but reading to this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_date_time.htm) to see how to add correctly the values you want could help. You need to write something like `+ interval '30 days'`. Note that I have done this search and found this link in less that 2minutes. I have no knowledge in postgresql specification